# Replicating a fat, clicky electric-bass

Tags: replication, electric-bass

I love the timbre of the electric bass that can be heard clearly at 0:44 and in other parts.

I imagine the bass guitar is using active pick-ups to get that clarity in the mid to high range. What else is going on? Is it DI or mic'ed?

Any suggestions you might have for replicating this beautiful tone would be appreciated!

Comment: It seems like the video or whatever it was isn't loading. Post a link instead of embedding it.

Answer (score 1):

@warriorbob found the video. dunno if it'll pop up if i edit that comment so i'm putting it here.

First of all, that bass definitely has some distortion on it. It MIGHT be overdrive, im not sure. I have a PD7 Phat Hed for my bass and it sounds pretty much the same. I know what you're referring to and that specific timbre comes from scratching the string lightly with a pick. It might even have to do with the way they slide theyre fingers on the frets. And to answer your question, yes, it's definitely got the treble up on the EQ because if you've ever listened to metal or metalcore you'd recognize that same sound coming from theyre amps and most metal bands completely cut out the mid range and boost bass and treble to like 9 or max. It's called a mid scoop, look it up if you want to play with this sound.